# For Loop only printing/storing last iteration

Tags: java, for-loop, iteration

Hope I can make myself clear enough.

I'm trying to measure how long does it take this program to multiply a couple of matrices and storing the result into another one (Called C).

I need to record the time going from 1 to 100, 1 to 200, 1 to 300, etc.

I'm actually measuring the time and storing the result into a .dat file for ploting later on (using gnuplot)

Thing is... When I run it, I get only the last iteration N times I wanted to measure. Let's say I'm trying from 1 to 100, I do get 100 iterations, but in the .dat file, I only get the last iteration. I'm sorry if I'm not making myself clear.

Here's the code and hopefully you can understand. Thank you!!

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class matrixMult 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        //Creating a new Scanner to get input from Stdin//
        Scanner input =  new Scanner(System.in);

        //Creates a variable to store the NxN dimension of the Matrices//
        int ms = input.nextInt();

        //Initializing Matrices and giving them the dimensions provided by the Stdin//
        int [] [] A = new int [ms] [ms];
        int [] [] B = new int [ms] [ms];
        int [] [] C = new int [ms] [ms];

        //Populating the Matrices with 1's and 0's//
        populatingMatrices (A);
        populatingMatrices (B);

        //Closing the Scanner after being used//
        input.close();

        long t_start;
        long t_end;
        long t_cost = 00000000000L;

        for (int x = 0; x < ms ;x++ ) 
        {
            //Starts the timer//
            t_start = System.nanoTime();

            //Storing the result of the matrices multiplication into C//
            C = mmm(A,B,C);


            //End the timer
            t_end = System.nanoTime();

            t_cost = t_end - t_start;

            System.out.println();
            System.out.println((t_cost / 1000000.0));
        }

    }//Main Method//

    //Method to populate Matrices with 1's and 0's//
    public static int [][] populatingMatrices(int A [] [])
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) 
        {   
            for (int j = 0; j < A[0].length; j++) 
            {   
                if (i == j) 
                {
                    A[i][j] = 1;
                }
                else 
                {
                    A[i][j] = 0;
                }
            }
        //Returns Matrix populated with 1's accross the diagonal axis, and 0's in all other elements of the Matrix//
        }return A;
    }  


    //Method to multiply Identity Matrices//
    public static int [][] mmm (int a [][], int b [][], int c [][])
    {
        int nr;
        int nc;
        nr = nc = a.length;

        for (int i = 0; i < nr; i++) 
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < nr ; j++ ) 
            {
                for (int k = 0;k < nr ;k++) 
                {
                    c[i][j] = c[i][j] + a[i][j] * b[k][j];      
                }   
            }
        }
        return c;
    }
}
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Single letter variables names and zero comments have made this unreadable.

Comment: How do you write the _.dat_ file ?

Comment: @DejaVuSansMono So don't bother even replying just to say that buddy. You're not really helping at all.

Comment: @Berger I'm writing to the .dat file through the command line bla.java > timing.dat.

Comment: Some of the things you are doing !?!  It seems you should get the start time right before the loop and get the end time right after the loop. To get in-between times create an arraylist and used an if statement to check when x = 100 or other values you want. At the end of the problem calculate the differences in times. I would use System.out.print until I get the results I want. Then I would add the store to file stuff.

Comment: The important and only thing to measure is the mmm method/function. I think I understand what you're refering to, but I believe it's not quite exactly what I "need" @SedrickJefferson. Maybe my explanation was not the best. I need to multiply 2 matrices and store the result into another one. What I want to measure is that. How much time does it take to do the actual multiplication. From 1x1 matrix up to a 100x100. I'm getting 100 iterations, all of them with the same measurement (Which it's obviously not ideal) It should be an ascending curve as N goes up. Did I make myself a bit clearer?Thanks

Comment: I think it's exactly what you need.

Comment: @SedrickJefferson cool... Thanks.

Comment: Also why use ms in your for loop? There is no relationship between your array size and the for loop in my example.

Comment: @SedrickJefferson The idea was that the for loop was going to iterate from 0 to N, N=ms. So, if I input ms=100, the idea was that the loop would go through. Do you get what I mean?

Comment: Yea, but is it always the case that your loop and you array size are equal. Let's say you wanted A[3][3], B[3][3],C[3],[3]. Do you also want your loop to run 3 times?

Comment: I'm sorry @SedrickJefferson , but I don't really understand what you're refering to. I'm not the best coder in the world... Maybe I'm missing something. I don't know... I just need a way to edit the existing code to make it work as I previously wrote. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You are only getting the last time of the most recent iteration because you are continuously overwriting the value of t_cost. You need to do a += to add to it each iteration of your for loop.

```
    long t_start;
    long t_end;
    long t_cost = 00000000000L;

    for (int x = 0; x < ms ;x++ ) 
    {
        //Starts the timer//
        t_start = System.nanoTime();

        //Storing the result of the matrices multiplication into C//
        C = mmm(A,B,C);


        //End the timer
        t_end = System.nanoTime();
        //use the += so you are adding to the previous iterations of your calcualted time
        t_cost += t_end - t_start;

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println((t_cost / 1000000.0));
    }
```

Comment: I tried your solution but It's plotting a straight line, which should not be the case. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I think "ms" in the for loop should be how many times you want the for loop to run. I can't see why that is associated with the array sizes that you are setting in your code above.

```
        ArrayList<long> al = new ArrayList()
        al.add(System.nanoTime());//Start time;
        for (int x = 0; x < ms ;x++ ) 
        {
            //Storing the result of the matrices multiplication into C//
            C = mmm(A,B,C); 

             if(x == 100 || x == 200)
             {
                 al.add(System.nanoTime());//at given points time
             }
        }
        al.add(System.nanoTime());//end time. if You end at a point that you check in the if statment like 200, then this is not needed.

        //now do your cost calculations using all the values stored in al.
```